# How do percentages get calculated in LibreOffice?

Tags: sql, excel, libreoffice-calc

Cell A1 contains value `0.974`, and cell A2 contains formula `=A1`.

Formatting for cell A1 is a number like `-1234.123`, and formatting for cell A2 is a percent like `-12.95%`.

The result shown in A2 is `97.35%`.

How is that being calculated?  And how do I convert that calculation to SQL?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce - 0.974 is 97.40% which is standard display of fraction as a percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the actual value of cell A1 is something like `0.9735`.  You can see the actual value by selecting the cell and looking in the [formula bar](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Parts_of_the_main_Calc_window).  Then it shows `0.974` when formatted to 3 decimal places, and cell A2 shows `97.35%` as you said.

It sounds like it is simply rounding the value in cell A1 to the nearest 3 decimal places.  To do this in SQL, use the [ROUND function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_round.asp).